# omitting 'what'

Tags: relative-pronouns

I know that you can omit ***what*** in the following sentence.

> There's more to it than ***what*** meets the eye.

Can I omit ***what*** in the following sentences? If not, what is the reason?

1. I had done three times more than (***what***) was needed
2. There's more to the bacon shortage than (***what***) has been reported
3. You've got more than (***what***) you thought.
4. What unites us is greater than (***what***) divides us.
5. It seems that we focus more on the impossibilities than (***what***) can be done.

Comment: 1 through 3 work.  4 and 5 don't.  I think it's because 1-3 express a single concept and "what" describes a variation in degree.  In 4 and 5, "what" compares two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a comparative, **what** can be omitted:

> more ... than needed
>   more ... than was needed
>   more ... than what was needed

When the comparands are nominals, **what** cannot be omitted:

> what unites us ... what divides us
>
> the impossibilities ... what can be done

Here is another example where there are nominal  comparands:

> My car is faster than what you drive.

my car ... what you drive